# get current request in 404 page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, httprequest

Hey I want to use the current request object as the facade not the static way(`$request` not `Request::`) in a custom 404 blade file.

I don't know if I can hint about it to the error handler or is there a way to create that object?

Should/Could I do it via the `Expections/Handler.php` file?

I've found [Here](https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-create-a-custom-404-error-page) the following answer:

```
//Create a view and set this code in app/Exception/Handler.php :

/**
 * Render an exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        return response()->view('missing', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}

 //Set this use to get it working :

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it from the Handler. Inside the *render()* method:

```
if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
    return response()->view('your.view.name', $dataYouWantToPass);
}
```

Comment: is that the "laravel" way to handle it?

Comment: @eric.itzhak Absolutely, you can read it in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler.

Comment: Thank you for your help.